# How to correctly position a GameObject basing on mouse positions?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mouse

I have a GameObject that I'm moving when I click it, based on my mouse position, but its position in the game is not the same as the position in the real screen.

Things to consider:

- My screen is of 1920x1080 (so as the game, its on Ortographic camera with an size of 540, yes its 2D)
- The rectangle of the resulting movable area of the screen is more likely a quarter of the screen size.

Here is my code:

```
if (dragging) {
    Vector3 mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
    float x = mousePosition.x/2>width/2?width/2-mousePosition.x/2:mousePosition.x/2;
    float y = mousePosition.y/2>height/2?height/2-mousePosition.y/2:mousePosition.y/2;
    sendoCarregado.transform.position= new Vector2(x,y);
}
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: Take a look at `Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint`

Comment: @AnotherUser its on the title, OMGtechy thanks, I have seen a topic on it in unity3d.com and it helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Following code is from custom Editor window but I believe the idea is clear.

```
var mousePos = new Vector3(
   Event.current.mousePosition.x, 
   Camera.current.pixelHeight-Event.current.mousePosition.y,
   0 
);

var worldPos = Camera.current.ScreenToWorldPoint( mousePos );
```

Comment: It gives me NullPointerException, dunno why.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if you can use this, but this is what I use for running a script by raycasting to move a waypoint that my object follow..you can use the ScreenToWorldPoint to find the point in the game form the mouses posion

```
void Shot()
{
        tid = coolDowntime;
        Debug.Log (Input.mousePosition);
        Vector2 Hitpoint = Input.mousePosition;

        Vector3 vec  = myCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Hitpoint);
        Vector3 dir = myCamera.transform.TransformDirection (Vector3.forward);

        Debug.Log ("fire");
        vec = myCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Hitpoint);
        Hitpoint = Input.mousePosition;
        myCamera.transform.TransformDirection (Vector3.forward);
        Debug.DrawRay(vec, dir * 1000000, Color.blue);
        audio.Play ();
    if(Physics.Raycast(vec, dir, out hit, 100000))
    {

        Debug.Log("Try to hit somthing");
        if (hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "Target")

        {
                myCamera.audio.Play ();
            Debug.Log("Ramt målet");
                hit.collider.SendMessageUpwards("GotHit", SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance but this actually doesn't help me.